# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pcos_edd_discount_code.replace')

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am using the following script to replace some text provided by a shortcode from a storefront/shopping plugin. You can see the following in action if you add an item to cart and go to checkout.

```
pcos_eddiscountcode = function () {
    var pcos_edd_discount_code = jQuery('#edd_discount_code').html();
    var new_pcos_edd_discount_code = pcos_edd_discount_code.replace('Click to enter it', 'Click here to enter it');
jQuery('#edd_discount_code').html(new_pcos_edd_discount_code);
};
```

Works fine, but it causes an issue on a totally seperate part of the plugin. You can see it [here (add to cart buttons are ignoring my css and forcing a page redirect on click).](https://beatpcos.com/store/)

I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pcos_edd_discount_code.replace')
```

I am totally new to javascript so any else is appreciated!

:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because when beatpcos_script.js gets loaded in the /store/ page, `pcos_eddiscountcode` gets called in the `jQuery(document).ready`. `pcos_eddiscountcode` only exists in the /checkout/ page, therefore jQuery cannot find the the id `#edd_discount_code` in the /store/ page, which is what gives you the undefined message.

To fix this, move the `pcos_eddiscountcode` function (and other necessary functions for /checkout/ page) to a separate javascript file, and include the checkout-specific javascript file only in the /checkout/ page.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.